# What changes are in the Monero 0.11.0.0 release?

Tags: monerod

0.11.0.0 was just released. What are the major changes in this version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Major improvements**

- minimum ringsize increased from 3 to 5
- mandatory RingCT for all transactions
- major synchronisation speed-up
- massively improved the blockchain import function
- changed terminology from "mixin" to "ring size"
- add a --fluffy-blocks option to relay blocks as fluffy blocks if possible
- allow for password verification without loading the subsequently unencrypted - - - wallet into RAM
- reduced privacy leak risks when using untrusted remote nodes

Full release notes can be found [on Github](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.11.0.0) as usual.